# Solve the integration by parts

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Solve this integration by parts

> ∫ln(x+1)/x dx

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash, how did you put the fraction? I didn't know how to put it so I put / instead of a fraction

Comment: Please show your work, and where you got stuck

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Here is a "quick" tutorial for syntax

Comment: This looks very close to dilogarithm, I doubt you can solve it by IBP

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: @ArielFishbein I don't think I have the integral right, so that's why I post here to someone solve it

Comment: @md2perpe No, I don't consider rewriting my post

Comment: @ArielFishbein thanks for the syntax tutorial web

Comment: Why rollback to before the syntax was applied?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash because I want to delete the question

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't delete a question that has been answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us make the change $x = -u$. Then, the integral becomes
$$ \begin{align*}\int \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x} dx &= \int \frac{\ln(1 - u)}{-u} d(-u) \\
&= - \int \frac{\ln(1 - u)}{-u} du\end{align*}$$

The value $f(z) = \int_0^z \frac{\ln(1 - u)}{-u} du $ is a standard complex function called Dilogarithm, which is denoted as $Li_2(z)$ (check [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilogarithm) for more information). To conclude your exercise,
$$ \begin{align*}- \int \frac{\ln(1 - u)}{-u} du &= - Li_2(u) + C \\ &= - Li_2(-x) + C\end{align*}$$
Hence,
$$ \begin{align*}\int \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x} dx = - Li_2(-x) + C\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks for trying to solve the integration

Comment: This question does not meet the [standards for the site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), and the OP even wrote "**I don't consider rewriting my post**". So, instead of answering it (which encourages low-quality questions), why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting some more comments to insist on this mandatory rewriting? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) regarding quality standards.